# How to use Firefox command line to download a specific image from a website?

Tags: command-line, firefox

Server: ubuntu 18.04
I intend to automate extracting a skychart from HevenAbove website. Now I can use the following command to download the whole page.

```
firefox -screenshot heavenabove.png 'https://heavens-above.com/SkyChart.aspx?lat=13.71732&lng=100.5907&loc=Europa+Cafe%27+Observatory%2c+Bangkok+Thailand&alt=0&tz=UCTm7' --window-size=1920,1080
```

I may use imagemagick convert cli to further cut and save the skychart part. I just wonder whether there is any cleaner option to just download by specifying, say, the img id name (for my case, img id="ctl00_cph1_imgSkyChart"); or some other option.

Thank you.

Comment: curl -o heavenabove.png "https://heavens-above.com/SkyChart.aspx?lat=13.71732&lng=100.5907&loc=Europa+Cafe%27+Observatory%2c+Bangkok+Thailand&alt=0&tz=UCTm7"

Comment: thanks. My question is, is it possible to extract only the skychart part (img id ctl00_cph1_imgSkyChart) with one command line?

Comment: document.querySelector('#ctl00_cph1_imgSkyChart').attributes["src"];

Comment: Do you have the full command line?

Answer (score 0):

The skychart part.

```
<img id="ctl00_cph1_imgSkyChart" src="wholeskychart.ashx?lat=13.71732&amp;lng=100.5907&amp;loc=Europa+Cafe%27+Observatory%2c+Bangkok+Thailand&amp;alt=0&amp;tz=UCTm7&amp;size=800&amp;SL=1&amp;SN=1&amp;BW=0&amp;time=58934.13842&amp;ecl=0&amp;cb=0" style="height:800px;width:800px;border-width:0px;">
```

Install curl

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Download the src.

```
curl -o heavenabove.png "https://heavens-above.com/wholeskychart.ashx?lat=13.71732&amp;lng=100.5907&amp;loc=Europa+Cafe%27+Observatory%2c+Bangkok+Thailand&amp;alt=0&amp;tz=UCTm7&amp;size=800&amp;SL=1&amp;SN=1&amp;BW=0&amp;time=58934.13842&amp;ecl=0&amp;cb=0"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The curl commands above did not work, even the simple curl command to get the whole webpage (return a small size output file that can't be open by the image viewer). I'm now using the firefox command line and imagemagick covert commands; though not elegant, but got what I want.